# Timespan of the Beta period

Tags: discussion

As a corollary to [this question](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/409/how-to-encourage-people-to-accept-an-answer) which rightly bemoans the lack of [question acceptance](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37041/raspberry-pi), is there a time limit on the Beta period?

I can see the criteria for [transition](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) to a full site and I see that the site can be deleted if usage peters out.  The site is certainly not petering out, so could the *Powers That Be* delete the site if it fails to graduate within a certain time?  Alternatively, could it survive in Beta for ever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately the decision is made by the Stack Exchange community team, though [here's a little information](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/).  It can, theoretically stay in beta indefinitely if there is not enough growth to promote it, but not enough 'petering out' to close it.  Essentially, *growth* is what determines whether a site will get promoted.  I don't have sources on this because the information came from the community team.

Comment: Just dropping by to confirm this. We typically review each site every 90 days or so to see how it's doing, but there is no time limit on how long a site can stay in beta. (Disclaimer for folks who haven't seen me before: I'm on the community team.)