# Being pressured to answer my own question

Tags: discussion

I have a question that is a few months old, and has no answer: [Logitech K700 keyboard doesn't show up in /dev/input](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10278/logitech-k700-keyboard-doesnt-show-up-in-dev-input?noredirect=1#comment21556_10278)

Today a user began pressuring me to add my own answer to the question, despite my explanation that... I don't **have** an answer to the question!

I understand that we want to improve the Question/Answer ratio - but is this really the way to do it?

Personally, I would rather hold out for a real answer. If it never comes, so be it. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Oh, I think that was me.  I wasn't trying to pressure you to answer, more suggesting.  I see what impact that had.  Sorry! :(. I was following http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/438/do-we-need-to-clean-up-the-number-of-un-answerd-questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not wrong, a user should never be pressured to accept an answer. I have addressed the issue with the user in question, and will continue to monitor the situation.

No this is not the right way to go about it as I have stated before, and as this [meta post](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/409/how-to-encourage-people-to-accept-an-answer/452#452) points out  the question is considered answered when it receives an upvote. I have expressed my concern previously that the blind pursuit of a  number (answer percentage) is a mistake. I firmly believe that by doing what we have in the past, namely, providing an open and welcoming community and striving to help others will lead us to graduation.

Comment: Great, thank you!